# Как вывести значение?

Tags: java, android

Есть такая строка

```
scoreLabel.setText(R.string.score + score);
```

`R.string.score` это ресурс с именем -  Очки:
просто `score`  - тут хранятся очки.

Если написать так, то всё работает

```
scoreLabel.setText("Очки:" + score);
```

Если так -

```
scoreLabel.setText(R.string.score + score);
```

то когда мой персонаж сталкивается с предметом, который добавляет очки, то игра вылетает.

Как так сделать по другому?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо написать:

```
scoreLabel.setText(getString(R.string.score) + score);
```

`setText()` принимает или `String/Spannable` или целое число - идентификатор ресурса.